# JSP scriplet tag

Tags: jsp

JSP code:

```
<% 
String name=rs.getString(2);
%>

<input type="text" name ="name" value='<%= name %>' style="color:black; background-color: #ffffff" required>
```

> Error: variable name cannot be resolved in the input tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any other errors before that? Is name already defined somewhere else? Which web container are you using?

Comment: Just check whether String name = rs.getString(2) is able to fetch the value properly...

Comment: rs.getString(2) is working properly.Just that cant assign value to my input box using <%= name %>

Comment: Your code as shown should work, I guess there is some other issue in your code. Are there any other errors? If you delete these two lines, is everyhting working fine?

Answer (score 0):

when you face issue and not able to resolve it, go step by step. Here is the approach i would to take first of all to determine the issue

Just keep the minimum info and then see what happens

```
<% 
String name="Scott";
%>

<input type="text" name ="name1" value='<%= name %>'>
```

2 Though every thing looks ok in your code. Make sure error is not in some other JSP. (May be in some inculded one). To rule out just make a simple jsp and has your code snippet only

Answer (score -1):

There is some problem in your syntaxt  rs.getString(2) and it is not fetching that value.So check it.
If you try in following way then it works fine without error.

```
  <% String name="User Name"; %>
  <input type="text" name ="name" value='<%= name %>' style="color:black; background-color: #ffffff">
```

Comment: There's a difference between not being able to resolve a variable and a variable not containing the expected value.

Comment: Hi Dave, but as per his syntax "variable name cannot be resolved in the input tag" this error did not came as he already declared the variable name as String in scriptlet.So I think that rs.getString(2) is the cause of problem.

Comment: The runtime fetch has nothing to do with any compile time error. Variable *resolution* has nothing to do with variable *content*. There may well be a typo or deployment issue not reflected here, but the content of a variable won't affect the compilers ability to take it. Null is an acceptable value from the compiler's point of view.

Comment: It's right but as name is already declared in scriptlet so there may be the problem in variable rs,so what's your opinion on it.